# How to update a row in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

**I have 2 PHP files for this. The first one update.php contains the user form to update the row. The next one,update_ac contains the coding to carry out this update. The problem is i do not get a proper output**

```
 <?php
    $host = "localhost"; // Host name 
    $username = "root"; // Mysql username 
    $password = ""; // Mysql password 
    $db_name = "yumyum"; // Database name 
    $tbl_name = "food"; // Table name
    // Connect to server and select database.
    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die("cannot connect");
    mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die("cannot select DB");

    // get value of id that sent from address bar
    //$id=$_GET['id'];

    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];

    // Retrieve data from database 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$id'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $rows = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    ?>

    <table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
        <form name="form1" method="post" action="update_ac.php">
            <td>
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">

                    <tr>

                        <td align="center"><strong>name</strong></td>
                        <td align="center"><strong>price</strong></td>
                        <td align="center"><strong>Quantity</strong></td>

                    </tr>

                    <td align="center">
                        <input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="<? echo $line['name']; ?>">
                    </td>

                    <td align="center">
                        <input name="price" type="text" id="price" value="<? echo $line['price']; ?>" size="15">
                    </td>

                    <td align="center">
                        <input name="Quantity" type="text" id="Quantity" value="<? echo $line['Quantity']; ?>" size="15">
                    </td>


                    <td>
                        <input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" value="<? echo $line['id']; ?>">
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
                    </td>

                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </form>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <?php
    // close connection 
    mysql_close();
    ?>

    **This is update_ac.php**
        <?php
        $host="localhost"; // Host name 
        $username="root"; // Mysql username 
        $password=""; // Mysql password 
        $db_name="yumyum"; // Database name 
        $tbl_name="food"; // Table name 

        // Connect to server and select database.
        mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
        mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

        // update data in mysql database 
        $sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET name='$name', price='$price', Quantity='$Quantity' WHERE id='$id'";
        $result=mysql_query($sql);

        // if successfully updated. 
        if($result){
        echo "Successful";
        echo "<BR>";
        echo "<a href='yumhome.php'>View result</a>";
        }

        else {
        echo "ERROR";
        }

        ?>
```

Comment: This is my output
name price Quantity
<? echo $row['name']; ?>

Comment: in update_ac.php it looks like you are missing `$id = $_REQUEST['id']`

Comment: @ jungsu heo do i need to do the same for name price and quantity?

Comment: @user2966446 Your script is wide open to MySQL injection attacks. Meaning, anyone can hack your database easily. You should be using PDO/Mysqli

Comment: @user2966446 of course you are

Comment: but how do i get the values of the fields of name price quantity to edit?

Comment: @user2966446 give me more Information about your situation. UPDATE is not working? (then "ERRO" shown?) or FORM is not displayed for edit.

Comment: @jungsu heo The form is displayed but the values of name, price and quantity are not displayed

Comment: `<form>` should sourround the `<table>`! Do not start a form-tag between tr and td.

Comment: is this typo? `value=<? echo $line["name"];?>`

Comment: @JungsuHeo It must be, unless he is using HTML5

Comment: @jungsu heoThis is the output that appears for  value of  name field <? echo $row['name']; ?>

Comment: @steven i changed $line to $row

Comment: @user2966446 It should be `$rows` not `$row`. Concentration please :-)

Comment: i used a tutorial for this the problem as jungsu and Qǝ uoɯᴉs say
is that the html appears in the output
here is the link to the tutorial
http://www.phpeasystep.com/mysql/9.html

Comment: @steven $rows also did not work

Comment: @user2966446 phpeasystep is too old fationed (and, update_ac.php is not work). I suggest buying recent PHP book and read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be that you need to fix different problems.

One after another...

1) try to display the form correctly with all values. if `$rows` doesnt work please do a `print_r($rows);` after `mysq_fetch_array...` and tell us what you see.

2) if the form is shown correctly go to the answer of @Machavity

I have time today so i was able to create a sample code using PDO to show how it could be done. Save it as index.php and replace the fieldnames, dbname, username, password with yours. It has been written fast and is untested but it should work. The form's action is the current php file so in this example there is no seperate file for the update stuff. Everything is in one file.

```
<?php
class db {
    public static function dbFactory($host, $dbase, $user, $pass) {
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbase", $user, $pass);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);        
        return $pdo;
    }
}


$id = isset($_REQUEST['id'])?intval($_REQUEST['id']):0;
if($id <= 0) {
    echo "Please specify the id!";
    exit;
}

$db = db::dbFactory('localhost','mydbname','myusername','mypassword');

if(isset($_POST['save'])){ // the update stuff
    $field1 = $_POST['field1'];
    $field2 = $_POST['field2'];
    $field3 = $_POST['field3'];    
    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPATE `mytablename` SET `field1` = :field1, `field2` = :field2, `field3` = :field3 WHERE `myid` = :id ");
    $stmt->bindValue(':field1', $field1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':field2', $field2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':field3', $field3, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $success = $stmt->execute();    

    if($success) {
        echo "Ok, data has been saved.";
    }
}

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `mytablename` WHERE `myid` = :id");
$stmt->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>


<form method="post" action="index.php">
<input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?php echo $id;?>'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Field1</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='field1' value='<?php echo $data['field1'];?>'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Field2</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='field2' value='<?php echo $data['field2'];?>'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Field3</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='field3' value='<?php echo $data['field3'];?>'></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <input type='submit' name='save' value='save me'>
</form>
```

Comment: changed `PDO::PARAM_INT` to `PDO::PARAM_STR` for the `bindValue` of field1, field2, field3 to be able to insert strings instead of integer values

Comment: @steven 
i get an error on lne 18
Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\wamp\www\yumyum\editindex.php on line 18
owing to $id = intval($_REQUEST['id']);

Comment: fixed it, but you need to specify the id eg: index.php?id=5

Comment: nice, i've recogniced that there are so many posts here based on the confusing tutorial you used. I should publish one by myself :-)

Answer (score 1):

In `update_ac.php` you're not using the `$_POST` superglobal. Some older versions of PHP will autoload those values for you but most modern versions do NOT. You also need to stop using `mysql` functions and switch to `mysqli`. Lastly, you need to [escape your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). I won't fix the `mysqli` for you, but I will show you the simplest way to fix your `UPDATE`. This is simplified for the OP.

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$price = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['price']);
$Quantity = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Quantity']);
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);

$sql = 'UPDATE ' . $tbl_name . ' SET 
        name = "' . $name . '", 
        price = "' . $price . '", 
        Quantity="' . $Quantity . '" 
    WHERE id="' . $id;
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: This is what appears in the field under name
<? echo $rows['name']; ?>

Comment: what shud appear is the name of an item located under field name

Comment: @ machavity r u there?

Answer (score 1):

This is not the answer but useful links you want.

### mysql_xxx() deprecated

those functions are deprecated for several reason.

- `mysql_connect()`
- `mysql_query()`
- `mysql_fetch_array()`
- and so on

use **`mysqli`** or **`PDO`**

['MySQLi' for Beginners](http://codular.com/php-mysqli) might help you. just read and modify code yourself.

### HTML5 and CSS3

I can't find examples using both `mysqli` and `HTML5`. But [This tutorial](http://tangledindesign.com/how-to-create-a-contact-form-using-html5-css3-and-php/) is great work for HTML5 and CSS3 using PHP

I have seen your profile and your questions, I hope these tutorial help you. good luck to you.